# My code doesn't give me the correct value

Tags: python, numpy

I'm doing this for a homework (sorry for my english) The problem is in the bold lines: idk exactly the problem but is like the xi+1 is taking the wrong values (I will explain at the end):

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.table import Table
def f(x): #function
    return x**3+2*x**2+10*x-20
#Initial Values, I put matrix of 100 because this method is for aproximation so we don't know how many iterations it will take
i=0
l=0.00004
e=np.zeros([100,1])
x=np.zeros([100,1])
a=np.zeros([100,1])
b=np.zeros([100,1])
G=np.zeros([100,1])
S=np.zeros([100,1])
a[0]=1
b[0]=3
    #Aproximation method
def FP(x,i,a,b):
    G[i]=f(b[i])
    F[i]=f(a[i])
    x[i]=(a[i]*G[i]-b[i]*F[i])/(G[i]-F[i])
    e[i]=abs(x[i]-a[i])
    while e[i]>l:
        if f(a[i])*f(x[i])>0:
            a[i+1]=x[i]
            b[i+1]=b[i]
            G[i+1]=f(b[i+1])
            F[i+1]=f(a[i+1])
#HERE
            x[i+1]=(a[i+1]*G[i+1]-b[i+1]*F[i+1])/(G[i+1]-F[i+1])
            if f(x[i])*f(x[i+1])>0:
                G[i+1]=G[i+1]/2
            e[i+1]=abs(x[i+1]-x[i])
            i=i+1
        elif f(a[i])*f(x[i])<0:
            a[i+1]=a[i]
            b[i+1]=x[i]
            G[i+1]=f(b[i+1])
            F[i+1]=f(a[i+1])
#AND HERE
            x[i+1]=(a[i+1]*G[i+1]-b[i+1]*F[i+1])/(G[i+1]-F[i+1])
            if f(x[i])*f(x[i+1])>0:
                F[i+1]=F[i+1]/2
            e[i+1]=abs(x[i+1]-x[i])
            i=i+1
        else:
            break
 #This is for the table so ignore it     
    im=range(0,i+1)
    xm=np.around(x[0:i+1],4)
    am=np.around(a[0:i+1],4)
    bm=np.around(b[0:i+1],4)
    em=np.around(e[0:i+1],4)
    Gm=np.around(G[0:i+1],4)
    Fm=np.around(F[0:i+1],4)
    fxm=np.around(f(x[0:i+1]),4)
    t = Table([im,am,bm,Fm,Gm,xm,fxm,em], names=('im','ai', 'bi', 'F','G','xi+1','f(xi+1)','e'))
    print(t)
```

**And when I evalue FP(x,i,a,b) in the second iteration there is something wrong**

```
im ai [1] bi [1]  F [1]  G [1] xi+1 [1] f(xi+1) [1] e [1] 
--- ------ ------ ------- ----- -------- ----------- ------
  0    1.0    3.0    -7.0  55.0   1.2258     -2.8948 0.2258
  1 1.2258    3.0 -2.8948  27.5   1.3145     -1.1275 0.0887
```

The xi+1 should be (ai*Gi-bi*Fi)/(Gi+Fi)  (it should takes the values of the same row) so xi+1=1.39478 (aprox) but the program gives me 1.3145 (aprox). 
I know the answer because I did the same in a texas n-spire CX CAS (really easier there) and also my teacher got the same answer.
Thank you

**THIS IS THE METHOD I'M USING**
[Algorithm pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWKPf.png)
**Fi=f(ai) and Gi=f(bi)**
The complete code in spanish (if you need to run)

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.table import Table
def f(x): #función 
    return x**3+2*x**2+10*x-20
#Valores iniciales
i=0
l=0.00004
e=np.zeros([100,1])
x=np.zeros([100,1])
a=np.zeros([100,1])
b=np.zeros([100,1])
G=np.zeros([100,1])
S=np.zeros([100,1])
a[0]=1
b[0]=3

#Aproximación por método de posición falsa
def FP(x,i,a,b):
    G[i]=f(b[i])
    F[i]=f(a[i])
    x[i]=(a[i]*G[i]-b[i]*F[i])/(G[i]-F[i])
    e[i]=abs(x[i]-a[i])
    while e[i]>l:
        if f(a[i])*f(x[i])>0:
            a[i+1]=x[i]
            b[i+1]=b[i]
            G[i+1]=f(b[i+1])
            F[i+1]=f(a[i+1])
            x[i+1]=(a[i+1]*G[i+1]-b[i+1]*F[i+1])/(G[i+1]-F[i+1])
            if f(x[i])*f(x[i+1])>0:
                G[i+1]=G[i+1]/2
            e[i+1]=abs(x[i+1]-x[i])
            i=i+1
        elif f(a[i])*f(x[i])<0:
            a[i+1]=a[i]
            b[i+1]=x[i]
            G[i+1]=f(b[i+1])
            F[i+1]=f(a[i+1])
            x[i+1]=(a[i+1]*G[i+1]-b[i+1]*F[i+1])/(G[i+1]-F[i+1])
            if f(x[i])*f(x[i+1])>0:
                F[i+1]=F[i+1]/2
            e[i+1]=abs(x[i+1]-x[i])
            i=i+1
        else:
            break
    #Esto es para la tabla        
    im=range(0,i+1)
    xm=np.around(x[0:i+1],4)
    am=np.around(a[0:i+1],4)
    bm=np.around(b[0:i+1],4)
    em=np.around(e[0:i+1],4)
    Gm=np.around(G[0:i+1],4)
    Fm=np.around(F[0:i+1],4)
    fxm=np.around(f(x[0:i+1]),4)
    t = Table([im,am,bm,Fm,Gm,xm,fxm,em], names=('i','ai', 'bi', 'F','G','xi+1','f(xi+1)','e'))
    print(t) 
FP(x,i,a,b)
```

Comment: I understand your code is derived from a formula, but the function and variable naming makes it incredibly hard to read or debug. Can you provide some context around the algorithm you are trying to implement, and at least add some spacing to your code?

Comment: Please, provide us the complete code. I have tried to run but `F` is never defined.

Comment: I tried to edit my post but I think is so confusing to explain  (the code is now there to run) and a pic for the algorithm